# Is it possible to change a voice of a caller in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to change a voice of a caller in iphone sdk ?

for example: 
            When person(A) calls person(B), voice of person(A) changed (like small baby voice, old man voice etc ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible as you have not control over the phone part.